# Is there a way to integrate handlebars-helpers with hapi?

Tags: handlebars.js, helper, view-helpers, hapi.js

I would like to use the [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) node module with my handlebars templates.  I'm using [hapi](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views) as my framework which supports handlebars.  I haven't found any documentation or examples that shows how to use handlebars-helpers with hapi using handlebars as the view engine.

Is it possible and if so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible according to hapijs api docs for views:

http://hapijs.com/api#serverviewsoptions

> helpersPath - the directory path where helpers are located. Helpers are functions used within templates to perform transformations and other data manipulations using the template context or other inputs. **Each '.js' file in the helpers directory is loaded and the file name is used as the helper name. The files must export a single method with the signature function(context) and return a string**. Sub-folders are not supported and are ignored. Defaults to no helpers support (empty path). Note that jade does not support loading helpers this way.

Looks as though handlebars-helpers has a different signature than what is required by hapi

Comment: That is the conclusion I came to.  I was hoping I was wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

after start hapi server

```
// hapi v17
try {
    await server.start();
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}

//......

// add some handlebars helpers    
let hbs = server.realm.plugins.vision.manager._engines.hbs;
// console.log('handlebars_helpers', handlebars_helpers);
if (handlebars_helpers) {
  for (let key in handlebars_helpers) {
    if (key) {
      // console.log('key', key, helpers[key]);
      hbs.module.helpers[key] = handlebars_helpers[key];
    }
  }
}
//check your helper is registered
// console.log('hbs.module.helpers', hbs.module.helpers);
// add some handlebars helpers
```